# Polymorphic instruction in Free Monad in Purescript

Tags: purescript, free-monad

I'm trying to get this small piece of code to compile.

```
module Sodium where

import Prelude
import Control.Monad.Free
import Data.Coyoneda
import Data.Tuple

data ReactiveF more
  = RFNewEvent (forall a. (Tuple (Event a) (a -> Reactive Unit) -> more))

type Reactive a = FreeC ReactiveF a

data Event a = Event a

newEvent :: forall a. Reactive (Tuple (Event a) (a -> Reactive Unit))
newEvent = liftFC $ RFNewEvent id
```

If I instead use "Number" instead of "a" in RFNewEvent, then everything compiles fine. But the moment I go "forall a." and replace "Number" with "a" it no longer compiles.

I get the following error message

```
Cannot unify type
  a1
with type
  a0
```

Does anyone know how to make this work?

I'm using version 0.5.0 of purescript-free.

**Edit**

If I use the following

```
data NewEventData = NewEventData forall a. Tuple (Event a) (a -> Reactive Unit)
```

and substitute it into RFNewEvent, then it will compile. But I end up with an undesired type signature for newEvent.

```
newEvent :: Reactive NewEventData
newEvent = liftFC $ RFNewEvent id
```

Which lets me create an event, but lets me shoot different event values to the event stream instead of the same type of value. (missing forall a. now on newEvent)

I might of made a mistake.

The overall goal is to simulate SodiumFRP's interface using a Free Monad. Then plug in an existing JavaScript FRP library that works similar to Sodium via FFI when interpreting the Free Monad.

Is this possible?

Comment: I suspect you want an existential quantifier, not a universal quantifier? Have you seen `purescript-exists`?

Comment: No I haven't seen purescript-exists. Having a look at it now. Although I may have made a mistake in my design.

Comment: @ Phil Freeman. Yes you are write. purescript-exists makes it possible to define "sample". (the next part i was stuck on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code now compiles and has the desired type signature for "newEvent"

```
module FRP.Sodium where

import Prelude
import Control.Monad.Free
import Data.Coyoneda
import Data.Tuple

data ReactiveF more
  = RFNewEvent (NewEventData -> more)

type Reactive a = FreeC ReactiveF a

data NewEventData = NewEventData forall a. Tuple (Event a) (a -> Reactive Unit)

data Event a
  = ENever
  | EMerge (Event a) (Event a)
  | EFilterJust (Event (Maybe a))
  | ECoalesce (a -> a -> a) (Event a)
  | EOnce (Event a)
  | ESplit (Event (Array a))
  | EVar Int

data Behaviour a = BVar Int

extractNewEventData :: forall a. NewEventData -> (Tuple (Event a) (a -> Reactive Unit))
extractNewEventData (NewEventData x) = x

newEvent :: forall a. Reactive (Tuple (Event a) (a -> Reactive Unit))
newEvent = map extractNewEventData $ liftFC $ RFNewEvent id
```

**Edit**

Also trying out purescript-exists. Makes it possible to define "sample"

RFSample gets added to ReactiveF ...

```
.
.
.
data ReactiveF more
  = RFNewEvent (NewEventData -> more)
  | RFSample (SampleData more)
.
.
.
data SampleDataF more a = SampleDataF (Behaviour a) (a -> more)
type SampleData more = Exists (SampleDataF more)

sample :: forall a. Behaviour a -> Reactive a
sample beh = liftFC $ RFSample $ mkExists $ SampleDataF beh id
```

Thank you Phil Freeman for your comment.